# Can't get information from Jframe sub class to normal main class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I cant get information which I type in Jtextfield from this class to the main class, I just get null

```
public class FirstWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String TEXT_FIELD = "text field";
    private static final String TEXT2_FIELD = "text field";
    private static final String PASS_FIELD = "pass field";

    private String loginname;
    private String loginlname;
    private String loginpass;

    public FirstWindow() {
        super("login");
        setSize(375, 125);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);// information inputs
        final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);// information inputs
        final JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);// information
                                                                    // inputs

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JButton showNamePasswordBtn = new JButton("Ok");
        showNamePasswordBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                loginname = textField.getText();// setting first value
                loginlname = textField2.getText();// setting sc value
                loginpass = new String(passwordField.getPassword());// setting
                                                                    // th value
                // System.out.println ("vardas  " +loginname);//information
                // holders works on this class
                // System.out.println ("varda  " +loginlname);
                // System.out.println ("vard  " +loginpass);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Vartotojo Vardas   ");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Vartotojo Pavarde");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("   Vartotojo Slaptazodis");

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        p.add(label, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        p.add(label2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        p.add(label3, gbc);

        p1.add(textField, TEXT_FIELD);
        p1.add(textField2, TEXT2_FIELD);
        p1.add(passwordField, PASS_FIELD);

        p2.add(showNamePasswordBtn);

        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public String back() { // tried getting back info
        return loginname;
    }// val1

    public String back1() {
        return loginlname;
    }// val2

    public String back2() {
        return loginpass;// val3
    }
}
```

And this is main class where i want get my information

```
public class GUImain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FirstWindow fw = new FirstWindow();
        fw.setVisible(true);
        String a, b, c;// creating strings
        a = fw.back();// setting val
        b = fw.back1();// setting val
        c = fw.back2();// setting val
        System.out.println("vardas  " + a);
        System.out.println("pavard  " + b);
        System.out.println("pass " + c);
    }
}
```

So main problem is everything id working fine expect i cant get any information from Jframe class which is pre most inportant

Comment: please cut out all irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code, the `main()` method is executed fist. It construct the GUI you want, and you can retrieve information as you want. eg: `textField.getText();`

But when the `main()` method is executed, you `TextField` are all empty, so they return `null`. The value you typed are stored in variables **only when you click on the button** because you add the listener on it. Try to output their value **after** you clicked on the button.

To see it: first remove this line from the listener: `System.exit(0);` (which stop your program), and add this to your `main()` to see you can get the value from `fw.back()` in your main class :

```
while(fw.back() == null){}
System.out.println(fw.back());
```

You will see the value

Comment: `public class GUImain {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  FirstWindow fw = new FirstWindow ();
  fw.setVisible(true);
  while(fw.back() == null){}
  System.out.println(fw.back());
 }
}`

well now I dont get value back